# Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-1.6.1

Tags: django, pip

I am going through [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DccH9AMwFQ) tutorial on Django. I have Django installed outside of the virtualenv, but inside, I try to use the same version as the linked video. I use the command

```
pip install django--1.6.1
```

but get the following error message:

```
(skillshare)skillshare$ pip install django--1.6.1
Downloading/unpacking django-1.6.1
    Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-1.6.1
Cleaning up...
    No distributions at all found for django-1.6.1 
    Storing debug log for failure in /Users/NAThompson/.pip/pip.log
```

The log file reads:

```
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/django--1.6.1/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django--1.6.1/: 
  404 Client    Error: Not Found
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django--1.6.1/ when looking for 
   download
  links for django-1.6.1
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for django-1.6.1:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/django--1.6.1/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/django--1.6.1/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django--1.6.1/: 
  404 Client Error: Not Found
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your command is wrong, that's right:

```
pip install django==1.6.1
```